# How do you center align inline elements inside an html div?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of spans inside a fixed width div. I would like to let the spans flow inline as they do by design. However, I would like them to be centered on each line instead of being left-aligned. How could I achieve this using css?

```
<div>
         <span>text1</span>
         <span>text2</span>
         <span>text3</span>
         <span>text4</span>
         <span>text5</span>
         <span>text6</span>
         <span>text7</span>
         <span>text8</span>
         <span>text9</span>
         <span>text10</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `text-align: center` to the div `<div class="dummy">`. Something like this...

```
.dummy {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/GA3Mf/)

Hope this is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Set a width for the div containing the spans and do this:

```
span {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this. It just put one span per line and floated it left. Not the behavior I am looking for.